# session remove from express bat not from socket.io

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

I destroy session on express but the session still a live in socket.io.
Here the code that destroy the session:

```
app.get("/delete", function(req, res) {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.end();
});
```

but if i run this code the session stil found:

```
socket.on("action", function() {
    if (socket.handshake.session.login) {
        console.log('session found!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right around the time that your client code is sending the `GET` request to your `/delete` route, you will want to disconnect by calling `socket.disconnect()` in your client code. Can you please post your relevant client code?